# 【robots.txt によりブロックされましたが、インデックスに登録しました】の対処法について

Tags: google-search

こんにちは。
【robots.txt によりブロックされましたが、インデックスに登録しました】という警告が何度もきて、サイト記事をリライトしても一向に改善されません。

いろいろ調べて試して見たのですが、どうにもできず改善方法を分かる方がいらっしゃれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。

警告されている数記事です。

[https://beauty-yk.jp/2020/01/06/サブリミック資生堂ワンダーシールドを現役美容/](https://beauty-yk.jp/2020/01/06/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E8%B3%87%E7%94%9F%E5%A0%82%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E7%8F%BE%E5%BD%B9%E7%BE%8E%E5%AE%B9/)

[https://beauty-yk.jp/2020/04/09/【2020年最新版】現役美容師が選ぶコスパを一切無/](https://beauty-yk.jp/2020/04/09/%E3%80%902020%E5%B9%B4%E6%9C%80%E6%96%B0%E7%89%88%E3%80%91%E7%8F%BE%E5%BD%B9%E7%BE%8E%E5%AE%B9%E5%B8%AB%E3%81%8C%E9%81%B8%E3%81%B6%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%91%E3%82%92%E4%B8%80%E5%88%87%E7%84%A1/)

[https://beauty-yk.jp/2020/04/23/【2020年最新】パーマをかけてる方におすすめ！髪/](https://beauty-yk.jp/2020/04/23/%E3%80%902020%E5%B9%B4%E6%9C%80%E6%96%B0%E3%80%91%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%82%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%99%E3%81%99%E3%82%81%EF%BC%81%E9%AB%AA/)

サイトはこちらです。

https://beauty-yk.jp/

こちらが2020年7月7日の最新更新したものです。

サイトの記事ほとんどがGoogle検索結果で『この記事には情報が記載されていません。』と表示されます。

Google検索ランキングで上位記事もこの通知が来た日を境にランキング結果がとても落ち込んで何ページも先にいかないと表示されなくなりました。

この検索結果は
【robots.txt によりブロックされましたが、インデックスに登録しました】
これと関係あるのでしょうか？
また改善方法をご存知の方教えていただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 1. 警告を送っているのは誰ですか？ (読み進めれば google なのかなとは思いますが…), 2. "色々調べて試した" ことを具体的に質問文に含めてみてください。 (既に試したことを回答する無駄を省くため)

Comment: 望ましい状態は以下のどちらでしょうか？「beauty-yk.jp/2020/... のページはGoogleの検索結果に一切出てこない」「beauty-yk.jp/2020/... のページはGoogle検索結果に出てきて、スニペットも表示される」

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは、Google Search Consoleで表示されている警告に関するご質問だと思います。
ご質問の際はこのことを本文とタイトルに明記していただけると、回答がされやすいと思います。

確認した限り当サイトのrobots.txtに問題はありませんので、ページ内にあるfacebookやtwitterのリンク先のrobots.txtが影響しています。
対応としては無視するか、ご自分で対応できる範囲であれば、robots.txtを編集します

- 該当ページをインデックスさせない(これは論外ですね)
- 原因となるリンク先をnofollowする

合わせて、公式のサポートページへの質問等をご確認ください

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203#indexed_though_blocked_by_robots_txt
https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/7904664?hl=ja

検索結果についてですが、これについてはわかりませんし、流動的なものかと思います。

ただ極力、エラーをなくしサイト内容やHTMLの内容、サーバーの応答速度を改善することで
ページの評価は向上するということは言われていますのでご対応は間違っていないと思います。

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ja

Page Speed Insightsの内容を確認して満点に近づけることで確実にサイトの評価は上がりますので、そちらもご検討ください。